# Make Gridview display checkboxes instead of 0s and 1s

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` that displays records that are either the number 1 or 0.

How can I convert the record into a check box which is checked if the value is 1 or unchecked if the value is 0?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStations" runat="server">
    <columns>
        <asp:templatefield headertext="Type" sortexpression="TypeDesc">
            <edititemtemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTypeEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TypeDesc") />
            </edititemtemplate>
            <itemtemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TypeDesc") ></asp:CheckBox>
            </itemtemplate>
            <itemstyle horizontalalign="Center" />
        </asp:templatefield>
        <asp:templatefield headertext="Type 2" sortexpression="TypeDesc2">
            <edititemtemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbType2Edit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TypeDesc2") />
            </edititemtemplate>
            <itemtemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbType2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TypeDesc2") ></asp:CheckBox>
            </itemtemplate>
            <itemstyle horizontalalign="Center" />
        </asp:templatefield>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Right now I can change them to an X if its a 1 and a "blank" if its a 0.

```
protected void gvStations_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= this.gvStations.Rows.Count - 1; i++)//from here down changes the 1's to X's and O's to blanks.
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= this.gvStations.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (j != 1 && j != 2)
            {
                if (this.gvStations.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text == "1")
                {
                    this.gvStations.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text = "X";
                }
                else if (this.gvStations.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text == "0")
                {
                    this.gvStations.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text = " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For display you can go as simple as a single comparison of the binded value:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTypeEdit" runat="server"
              Checked='<%# (int)Eval("TypeDesc") == 1 %>'/>
```

For handling editing of the grid row I am afraid you need to handle the GridView's  `RowUpdated` event and convert the values manually.

Comment: I get this error: CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Apollo, sorry, `Eval` is the right to use here. In fact, there is no such method as Bind at all. Forgot about this, apologies

Answer (score 1):

I think that should be:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTypeEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TypeDesc") %>' Checked="<%# (Int)Eval("TypeDesc") == 0 ? false : true %>" />
```

Comment: I get this error: CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

A simple helper function would be better as you have `TypeDesc` and `TypeDesc2`.

Markup

```
Checked='<%# SetCheckedStatus(Bind("TypeDesc")) %>'
Checked='<%# SetCheckedStatus(Bind("TypeDesc2")) %>'
```

Code-behind

```
protected bool SetCheckedStatus(object typeDesc)
{
    var isChecked = false;
    var intValue = 0;
    if (typeDesc != null)
    {
        int.TryParse(typeDesc.ToString(), out intValue);
        if (intValue == 1) { isChecked = true; }
    }
    return isChecked;
}
```

Much cleaner markup this way